# What WPF control can I use for a list of readonly items on WP7?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-phone-7, listbox

Right now I use a ListBox but that allows the user to select an item which I don't want. Is there a way to disable selecting or a more suitable control I can use?

Right now I have this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PersonNames}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: You can't use any WPF control. WP7 only runs SilverLight.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say SL as a subset of WPF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an `ItemsControl`, it's a base class without selection. (As it does not provide its own `ScrollViewer` you may need to add one (either in the template or around the control) if you need scrolling)

Comment: Thanks, I actually need a scrolling, but feel it's gonna get complicated to implement one myself.

Comment: @JoanVenge You don't need to implement scrolling yourself, just add a `ScrollViewer` around the `ItemsControl`. `<ScrollViewer><ItemsControl> ... </ItemsControl></ScrollViewer>`

Answer (score 1):

See the [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx) control.

Comment: Is ListView available on WP7?

Comment: It should be...? If it doesn't, it would be pretty easy to write. Did you google it?

Comment: Thanks, yes and I saw some people saying there is none in Silverlight/WP7.